# How to generate URL like blog post (www.abc.com/how-to-learn-php) in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, url-rewriting, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I want to generate user's profile URL like a blog post (www.abc.com/profile/tom-cruise-brad-pit). Each user's profile has a unique ID in the database, and I don't want to show the user's profile ID in the URL.

Comment: It will help you with that [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39951509/laravel-how-to-hide-url-parameter]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Resource Controller Slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080420/laravel-resource-controller-slug)

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar yes it is near to my question but in my question, there are two variable one is profile ID that i want to hide and second is profile name that i want to show.

Comment: @Arikael in this is its possible of duplicacy of slug, two person can use same slug.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided below will be helpful [eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)